# VHDL latch issues (flip-flops are not an option)

Tags: vhdl

I have to design a small-scale CPU with RAM and I'm facing a problem I can't handle. First, my code:

This is the RAM

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity memory is
 Port(
    clk: IN std_logic;
    instruction: IN std_logic;
    address : IN std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    ibus: IN std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    obus: OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
 );
end memory;
architecture Behavioral of memory is

type memArr is array (integer range <> ) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal mem: memArr (0 to 65535);
signal rom: memArr (0 to 128);
signal ram: memArr (0 to 65407);

begin

-- LOAD/STORE Test

    rom(0) <= "10100110";   -- step 1: (constant) load data1 into reg_addr1
    rom(1) <= "00000000";   -- this one/

    rom(2) <= "11100111";   -- step 2: (direct) load data2 from following address into reg_addr2
    rom(3) <= "00000000";   -- this address  
    rom(4) <= "01000000";   -- contains data2/

    rom(5) <= "10100000";   -- step 3: (constant) load followig data into reg_1
    rom(6) <= "01010101";   -- this one/

    rom(7) <= "10001000";   -- step 4: (indirect) store data in reg_1 to adress in reg_addr 1 + 2/

    rom(64) <= "00000000";  -- data2 from step 2


    mem(0 to 128) <= rom;

    reading: process (clk, instruction, address)
    begin
        if clk ='1' and instruction = '0' then
            obus <= mem(conv_integer(unsigned(address)));
        end if;
    end process;

    writing: process (clk, instruction, address, ibus)
    begin
        if clk ='1' and instruction = '1' then
            ram(conv_integer(unsigned(address))) <= ibus;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

This is the CPU:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity cpu is
    Port(
    clk: IN std_logic;
    rst: IN std_logic;
    instruction: OUT std_logic;
    address : OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    obus: OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    ibus: IN std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
    );
end cpu;

architecture Behavioral of cpu is
    --signal reg_1, reg_2, reg_3, reg_4, reg_5, reg_acc, reg_addr1, reg_addr2: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    signal pointer, s_pointer: std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    signal state, s_state, test: integer range 0 to 3;
    signal read3, s_read3, execute, s_execute: std_logic;

    type reg is array (integer range <>) of std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    signal registers: reg (0 to 7);
    signal handler: reg (0 to 2);

begin

---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---
---
---     Slave process (runs at '0')
---
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH--- 

    slave: process (clk, s_pointer, s_state, s_read3, s_execute)
    begin
        if clk = '0' then
            pointer <= s_pointer;
            state <= s_state;
            read3 <= s_read3;
            execute <= s_execute;
        end if;
    end process;

---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---
---
---     Master process (runs at '1')
---
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH--- 

    master: process (clk, rst, ibus, pointer, state, read3, execute)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            s_state <= 0;
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---
---
---     FSM to read instructions
---
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---         
        elsif clk = '1' and state = 0 then          
            s_state <= 1;
            s_pointer <= "0000000000000000";
            address <= "0000000000000000";
            s_read3 <= '0';
            s_execute <= '0';
            instruction <= '0';
            handler(0) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
            handler(1) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";       
            handler(2) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
        elsif clk = '1' and execute = '0' then
            address <= pointer;
            s_pointer <= pointer + 1;
            if state = 1 then
                instruction <= '0';
                handler(0) <= ibus;
                handler(1) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
                handler(2) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
                if (ibus(0 to 2) = "101" or ibus(0 to 2) = "110") then
                    test <= 1;
                    s_state <= 2;
                elsif ibus(0 to 2) = "111" then
                    --test <= 2;
                    s_state <= 2;
                    s_read3 <= '1';
                elsif (ibus(0) = '0' or ibus(0 to 2) = "100") then
                    test <= 3;
                    s_execute <= '1';
                end if;
            elsif state = 2 then
                handler(1) <= ibus;
                if read3 = '1' then
                    s_state <= 3;   
                    s_read3 <= '0';
                elsif read3 = '0' then
                    s_state <= 1;
                    s_execute <= '1';
                end if;
            elsif state = 3 then
                handler(2) <= ibus;
                s_state <= 1;
                s_execute <= '1';
            end if;

---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---
---
---     Execution phase
---
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH---

        elsif clk = '1' and execute = '1' then
            --not yet implemented
            s_execute <= '0';
        end if;
    end process; 

end Behavioral;
```

Both modules are linked in this top module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity microprocessor is
    Port(
    clk: IN std_logic;
    rst: IN std_logic
    );
end microprocessor;

architecture Behavioral of microprocessor is

component memory is
    Port(
    clk: IN std_logic;
    instruction: IN std_logic;
    address : IN std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    obus: OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    ibus: IN std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
    );
end component;

component cpu is
    Port(
    clk: IN std_logic;
    rst: IN std_logic;
    instruction: OUT std_logic;
    address : OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
    obus: OUT std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
    ibus: IN std_logic_vector(0 to 7)
    );
end component;

signal address: std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
signal ctrbus: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal rtcbus: std_logic_vector(0 to 7);
signal instruction: std_logic;

begin
memory1: memory port map (
            clk => clk,
            instruction => instruction,
            address => address,
            ibus => ctrbus,
            obus => rtcbus
            );
cpu1: cpu port map (
            clk => clk,
            rst => rst,
            instruction => instruction,
            address => address,
            ibus => rtcbus,
            obus => ctrbus
            );
end Behavioral;
```

Okay, I know that's quite a lot of code, but I would really appreciate any help.
So, my problem is, that when simulating, at the 5th clock cycle, weird things happen. At that moment, the RAM puts "11100111" onto its obus, so the CPU is here:

```
if state = 1 then
    instruction <= '0';
    handler(0) <= ibus;
    handler(1) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
    handler(2) <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
    if (ibus(0 to 2) = "101" or ibus(0 to 2) = "110") then
        test <= 1;
        s_state <= 2;
    elsif ibus(0 to 2) = "111" then        <<<===== HERE
        --test <= 2;
        s_state <= 2;
        s_read3 <= '1';
    elsif (ibus(0) = '0' or ibus(0 to 2) = "100") then
        test <= 3;
        s_execute <= '1';
    end if;
```

This is seen working in the simulation, because s_state and s_read3 both get their respective values. However, the last condition somehow also gets executed, because s_execute also changes to '1'! I don't understand how this is possible, how can this

```
ibus(0 to 2) = "111"
```

and this

```
(ibus(0) = '0' or ibus(0 to 2) = "100")
```

be true at the same time?

Many thanks in advance, 
Reygok

Comment: You really need to learn the difference between `clk = '1'` and `rising_edge(clk)` and rewrite the whole lot as proper clocked processes before going any further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these processes are no flip-flops, they are latches, and they are supposed to work without rising_edge(clk). That's a premise given from the teacher.

Comment: That is such a strange constraint that the question could usefully have mentioned you specifically want latches. So, you are on your own. Suspect glitches awakening processes, or sensitivity list errors. Add asserts in every branch to find out exactly what is happening and when. And understand why each one triggers. You'll have to debug it yourself. Oh, and the purpose of the exercise is probably to reinforce the merits of clocked processes...

Comment: I've been trying for hours to debug it myself by checking the signals at every branch and understanding what happened and when. But I can't figure it out, which is why I came here. And that's certainly not the purpose of the exercise, since it's the only one we have this whole semester. The whole course is just this project.

Comment: Your design appears to demonstrate why some designs use multi-phase (non-overlapping) clocks  allowing the use of latches instead of registers (fewer gates).  Successive stages updating and evaluating without propagating inappropriate events (glitches) based on combinatorial delays. Never evaluate an expression as a latch input in the same clock phase any of it's inputs are latched.  This could require increasing the number of states, latches for translating clock phases  or using more than two clock phases.

Comment: You have either misunderstood the task given by the teacher, or you have a very bad teacher.
You simply don't design a CPU using latches. Ever. Because it is close to impossible to make it work reliably.
As a general rule you never use latches. If you think you need a latch, then you are typically thinking wrong.
There are only a few extreme cases where latches are valid, typically in extremely simple logic without any clock at all.

Comment: @TimmyBrolin: I'm not an expert at all, so I can't really tell, but I don't think he's a bad teacher, bevause he worked for Swatch (a swiss watch company) for years, and developed, well, watches for them. Only in the research department however.

Comment: @EML: For example: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/why-are-inferred-latches-bad
The issues with latches are the same for both FPGA and ASIC design.

There is simply no advantage in designing a CPU using latches, but tons of verification problems.

Comment: @TB: the only issue with latches is that some STA tools don't handle them well, or at all, which is why you see recommendations not to use them in FPGA designs. On FPGAs you also have to build them from cells which aren't built for the job, which is bad. Otherwise, latches are smaller, cheaper, faster, and use less power. Latch-based processors used to be common - remember all those micros with 2-phase clocks? The question you cite is low quality - only Oli G's is of any value. The accepted answer is useless (clue: an edge-triggered flop is *also* "an asynchronous storage element").

Comment: I talked to my teacher about all this, and his answer was very clear: he knows very well that flip flop are easier, and less error-prone, but the design we have to implement is the real one Intel used in their cpu's during the 80's. The advantage of latches is there is no circuit race problem. It's not the optimal design for FPGA's or for educational purposes, but it's the true way of designing a cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's too much code here, but some general comments:

- Your master process should be transparent when `clk` is high, and latch otherwise. However, it doesn't work when `execute` has a metaval on it. Refactor it to have a single outer `if clk='1'`, like your slave process
- The reset in your master process is suspicious. It clears only one signal, leaving everything else unaffected. So, you've got a complex multi-function latch. Think about this again: reset all signals, or (better) move the reset inside the outer `if clk='1'`, or (even better) explicitly implement the reset as `AND` gates outside the latch process. Keep the latch as simple as possible.
- use `(others => '0')`, etc, instead of long lists of `0`/`Z`
- get rid of `std_logic_arith`/`std_logic_unsigned`. At first sight,
  you don't even need them. If you do need them, always use
  `numeric_std` instead, unless you have a very good reason not to

On your specific question: the 2 conditions can't be true at the same time, but they don't have to be. What's happening is that `ibus` is changing its state while `clk` is `1`. When it has one value, your code sets `s_state` and `s_read3`; when it has another value, it sets `s_execute`. The other signals remain unchanged, because you're not assigning to them.

You don't assign `ibus`, so you need to find out why it's changing. Should you latch it in your slave process?

You should probably also go back and confirm that any signals that aren't explicitly changed in any path through your master process actually end up with correct values. Your master code is suspicious, if only because it wasn't obvious to you that `ibus` might change and effectively latch some signals even though they're meant to be transparent when `clk` is `1`. You may need to re-design: clear *all* your master outputs as the first action after the outer `if clk='1'`, and then assign to *all* the outputs, whatever the current state of the inputs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Today I asked my teacher, and he told me the problem is in fact that ibus changes, and activates the latch. This is because at the beginning of the master process, I change "address", which is a bus to the RAM. So the RAM sends a new value over the ibus, since it's pointed to a new address. Also, the execute bit is in fact wrong, or at least not how it should be, this functionality should be implemented via a state 4; this will also get rid of some of the other problems you mentioned. Anyway, thanks again, you helped the most :)